# Python, Numpy: How to select numpy array with given mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, set-difference

For example, given a (10000, 250) sized numpy matrix A

```
>>>A.shape
(10000, 250)
```

and a numpy mask array `m`

```
>>>m = np.arange(0, A.shape[0], 3)
>>>m
([0, 3, 6, 9, ....., 9997])
```

This will select wanted column of `A`

```
>>>A[m]
>>>A[m].shape
(3333, 250)
```

But my question is. how to select the rest of the `A`? `A[([1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, ...., 9998, 9999, 10000])]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) to select all indices that do not belong to `m`:

```
A[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(A.shape[0]), m)]
```